# Radio Select with Image but Hide Radio Button and use image to select

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, opencart

Using opencart version 2.0.0

Within the Product.tpl page there is a foreach option loop that contains this

```
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'image') { ?>
          <div class="form-group<?php echo ($option['required'] ? ' required' : ''); ?>">
            <label class="control-label"><?php echo $option['name']; ?></label>
            <div id="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>">
              <?php foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
              <div class="radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" />
                  <img src="<?php echo $option_value['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $option_value['name'] . ($option_value['price'] ? ' ' . $option_value['price_prefix'] . $option_value['price'] : ''); ?>" class="img-thumbnail" /> <?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
                  <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
                  (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
                  <?php } ?>
                </label>
              </div>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
          </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

Which is all fine and working. But what i want to know, is, I see that they've wrapped the Input in a Label class. Because this is an image select, I can have a small 50px image of a colour, to select an option, and you can click on the image itself as opposed to clicking on the radio button to select it.

what i want to know is, using the jsfiddle i've made http://jsfiddle.net/8fqqrstq/ I want to remove the radio button itself using

`input[type="radio"] { visability: hidden; }`

But people still click on the image to select that option. BUT!, Whe the option is selected, a :checked css is used to change the border of the image to say

```
border: solid 1px #ff0000
```

How would i go about doing this?

Comment: Go read up on the _adjacent sibling combinator_.

Comment: I know about adjacent sibling combinator, usually you'd have input:checked + label {}.... ect.... but this isn't adjacent, the label is wrapped around the input.

Comment: So what? You wanted to format the `img`, and those _are_ adjacent siblings of your input elements.

Comment: Kudos to you sir, it was staring me right in the face!



input[type="radio"]:checked + img { border: solid 1px #ff0000; }

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I was having the same problem and wanted to post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fqqrstq/12/) link to show what you were trying to do in case someone else was a bit confused on it!

The only thing changed is that I removed the text next to each option and gave each radio button the same name so that only one could be selected! I also used

```
display:none;
```

instead of

```
visibility: hidden;
```

for the radio buttons so that extra space isn't taken up.

This is the CSS that shows how to use images as options without showing the radio button too.

```
div.radio img { border: solid 1px #bbb; padding: 2px; }
div.radio label { font-family: arial; }
input[type=radio]{ display: none; }
input[type=radio]:checked + img { border: solid 1px #ff0000; }
```